# Get more backreferences from regexp than parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Ok this is really difficult to explain in English, so I'll just give an example.

I am going to have strings in the following format:

```
key-value;key1-value;key2-...
```

and I need to extract the data to be an array

```
array('key'=>'value','key1'=>'value1', ... )
```

I was planning to use regexp to achieve (most of) this functionality, and wrote this regular expression:

```
/^(\w+)-([^-;]+)(?:;(\w+)-([^-;]+))*;?$/
```

to work with `preg_match` and this code:

```
for ($l = count($matches),$i = 1;$i<$l;$i+=2) {
    $parameters[$matches[$i]] = $matches[$i+1];
}
```

However the regexp obviously returns only 4 backreferences - first and last key-value pairs of the input string. Is there a way around this? I know I can use regex just to test the correctness of the string and use PHP's `explode` in loops with perfect results, but I'm really curious whether it's possible with regular expressions.

In short, I need to capture an arbitrary number of these `key-value;` pairs in a string by means of regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to validate the input while you extract the matches:

```
/\G(?=(?:\w++-[^;-]++;?)++$)(\w++)-([^;-]++);?/
```

`(?=(?:\w++-[^;-]++;?)++$)` is the validation part.  If the input is invalid, matching will fail immediately, but the lookahead still gets evaluated every time the regex is applied.  In order to keep it (along with the rest of the regex) in sync with the key-value pairs, I used `\G` to anchor each match to the spot where the previous match ended.

This way, if the lookahead succeeds the first time, it's guaranteed to succeed every subsequent time.  Obviously it's not as efficient as it could be, but that probably won't be a problem--only your testing can tell for sure.

If the lookahead fails, `preg_match_all()` will return zero (false).  If it succeeds, the matches will be returned in an array of arrays: one for the full key-value pairs, one for the keys, one for the values.

Answer (score 2):

regex is powerful tool, but sometimes, its not the best approach.

```
$string = "key-value;key1-value";
$s = explode(";",$string);
foreach($s as $k){
    $e = explode("-",$k);
    $array[$e[0]]=$e[1];
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in OP: `I know I can use regex just to test the correctness of the string and use PHP's explode in loops with perfect results`

Comment: So... you know this works but you don't want to use it because you would rather use a regex even though regex isn't the right tool for the job.  Is the regex a real requirement, or are you just trying to do it that way because it should work?

Comment: Read the OP, or should I quote it once more? It's only a couple of paragraphs long, if it is too hard for you to read it, please refrain from smart ass comments.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead. Maybe something like:

```
$matches = $parameters = array();
$input = 'key-value;key1-value1;key2-value2;key123-value123;';

preg_match_all("/(\w+)-([^-;]+)/", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
   $parameters[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}

print_r($parameters);
```

EDIT:

to first validate if the input string conforms to the pattern, then just use:

```
if (preg_match("/^((\w+)-([^-;]+);)+$/", $input) > 0) {
    /* do the preg_match_all stuff */
}
```

EDIT2: the final semicolon is optional

```
if (preg_match("/^(\w+-[^-;]+;)*\w+-[^-;]+$/", $input) > 0) {
    /* do the preg_match_all stuff */
}
```

Comment: As this is the only answer in vein with my question I give you a `+` and will accept it if no one proposes a better sollution, but the regexp does not verify the string given (`'foo-bar-baz'` would be treated as valid values)

Comment: so for `'foo-bar-baz'` you want `'foo' => 'bar-baz'` or `'foo-bar' => 'baz'` ? i can easily give you the alternate regex  ;)

Comment: for `'foo' => 'bar-baz'` use regex `/(\w+)-([^;]+)/` instead

Comment: No, I'd rather it'd fail altogether and not give any results, in my understanding the only such regex is mine (even though it can't be used in fetching data, only validating it). I'm sorry I did not mention validation of input in my OP, but the main answer seems clear. I'm going to wait one day before accepting your answer though.

Comment: Again, the leading semicolon `;` is (highly) optional, so still my regex stands :)

Comment: That's really mature of you to bad mouth me in your public answer whilst bringing NOTHING new to the discussion - only proving me right.

Comment: feeling a bit touchy, aren't you? fine, i've removed the 'bad-mouthing' part so that you can be prouder of your case .. thanks for the very clear question.

Answer (score 0):

No. Newer matches overwrite older matches. Perhaps the `limit` argument of `explode()` would be helpful when exploding.

Answer (score 0):

what about this solution:

```
$samples = array(
    "good" => "key-value;key1-value;key2-value;key5-value;key-value;",
    "bad1" => "key-value-value;key1-value;key2-value;key5-value;key-value;",
    "bad2" => "key;key1-value;key2-value;key5-value;key-value;",
    "bad3" => "k%ey;key1-value;key2-value;key5-value;key-value;"
);

foreach($samples as $name => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/^(\w+-\w+;)+$/", $value)) {
        printf("'%s' matches\n", $name);
    } else {
        printf("'%s' not matches\n", $name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The final semicolon `;` is not required. Also this only verifies the input, I'd like the regex to verify AND create an array.

Comment: yeah, I haven't realized that you need the data too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do both validation and extraction of data with one single regexp, as you need anchors (`^` and `$`) for validation and `preg_match_all()` for the data, but if you use anchors with `preg_match_all()` it will only return the last set matched.