# RegEx two equal characters in String

Tags: java, regex

I'm starting with RegEx and I need help, I want to validate that there are two equal characters followed by A, or that they are separated (but remain the same) and in the middle A. I explain with examples:

```
BBA -> true
ABB -> true
BAB -> true
CCA -> true
ABC -> false
BAC -> false
BBBA -> false (there have to be only two)
ABBB -> false (there have to be only two)
```

At the moment I have something similar to this, but it does not work correctly:

```
(([B-Z])\1{2}A) | ([B-Z]{1}A[B-Z]{1}) | (A([B-Z])\1{2})
```

I know I'm not getting close to the correct answer, what I'm learning. If someone could give me a hand I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: In general you probably need to look into backreferences and how to use them with capture groups, so that you can match a character depending on currently captured one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428545/java-regex-how-to-back-reference-capturing-groups-in-a-certain-context-when-the

The problem is in your case things like `[A-Z]{2}` will match `AB`, `AZ` and any other 2-symbol regexes, and I don't see a good way to express "same letter from this set repeated" other than like `A{2}A | B{2}A | C{2}A` etc, or using capture groups with backreferences.

Comment: But I would avoid solving this kind of problem with regex, it becomes too complex and brittle. Extract 2 first letters in regex, then check if they're the same in java.

Comment: This answer may help you :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16717823/7560986

Answer (score 1):

Use `\b` to match only words, and back references for each `|`.

```
\b([B-Z])\1A|([B-Z])A\2|A([B-Z])\3\b
```

Check: https://regexr.com/42bp0

Comment: Thank you very, very, very much! It works perfectly! I've been thinking about how to solve it for hours. Now I need to understand how it works and keep studying. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: The one mistake i spot in your regex is `([B-Z])\1{2}` actually refer to 3 of the same character, because `([B-Z])` is already referring to one, while `\1{2}` refer to 2 more.

Comment: This incorrectly matches `BABA` and `BBAA` due to the lack of trailing `\b` in the first two alternatives, and `ABAB` and `AABB` due to lack of leading `\b` on the last two alternatives. The fixed version would be `\b([A-Z])\1A\b|\b([A-Z])A\2\b|\bA([A-Z])\3\b` or by grouping the alternatives, `\b(?:([A-Z])\1A|([A-Z])A\2|A([A-Z])\3)\b`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done rather elegantly:

`\b(?=[A-Z]{3}\b)A?([B-Z])A?\1A?\b`

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rX4Pxj/1)

The `[A-Z]{3}` inside the lookahead asserts that the sequence is exactly 3 letters in length, thanks to having `\b` on both sides. The `A?([B-Z])A?\1A?` asserts that there are two identical instances of letter other than `A`, which can have `A` interspersed with it at any point, and thanks to also being flanked by `\b` on both side, asserts that nothing else is mixed in.

---

This can also be generalized to any number of repeats:

`\b(?=[A-Z]{3}\b)(?:\1|(?!\2)([B-Z])()|(?!\3)A())+\b\2`

Just change `{3}` to whatever number of total characters you want (i.e., the number of repeats plus 1 for the "A").

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rX4Pxj/2)
[Try it online! (Java)](https://tio.run/##jVJNT9tAEL37VwyWELstXoVWvcQKke1rQUi5EXNYnHW8qb22djdABZb4ZfwY/kg6/sJpShF7sOfNm/dmZu0Nv@PeZvVrt5NFVWoLG0ywrZU5@@I7/@S0WIsHdsFtkgn9X/6KWyu08h2n2t7mMoEk58bABZcKHh2APmsst/i6K@UKCuQILKyWag1cr83yBmhbDNDbgYbZELOkLCqZC@LG8S2Zz5aBd33z@KNGRMl8GsdnT2R@FMffKFmGSFFCu8R3GhBKv2Idki712waLhCslNEhVbS02UeJ@yJHFb2NFwaTqa@8zbAukLWUZN5fiwaJjPyoMK@RSCXTqyhTW/MQE6T0A@huEAms0KzpEGtFbiUyBFCyVarVvjw26gUr0rbCVTYnbua2myB6bWLmn8JfTuxoYD14DpKXGnSzIWcHwu2hLJtSX5xNfeh49lJMTODnQCBxzQr1PiV@fXxr5IZGr8X5qELkRH2@tSmgvbvr@1rUzPGun3u3CMAhD8M7B6q1wMN5DDTWiKAqiaA8hHnXNaVDKm/lIknG1FuC2P5kLtsQwGMJ2OrCZNBRtsMmbsHHd88FxkB9hGEThCP8A)

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([B-Z])\\1A|A([B-Z])\\2|([B-Z])A\\3")
```

back references run through the whole pattern and crosses OR operator. In general it is not a good fit for regex solution though as others mentioned.

Note that you have to add ^ and $ as needed to match only this pattern like so:

```
"^([B-Z])\\1A\$|^A([B-Z])\\2\$|^([B-Z])A\\3\$"
```