# PHP regex matching <html> tag with optional attributes

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to match `<html>` tag with optional attributes and to extract those attributes. I want to match one of the following variations of `<html>` tag. It would be the starting content of a HTML document or there may be `DOCTYPE` declaration before `<html>`.

```
<html>
<html lang="en">
<html class="my-class">
<html class="my-class" lang="en">
```

The regular expression pattern I'm trying is as below, but it is only matching the last attribute `lang="en"` for the fourth case.

```
/<html(\s+([a-z\-]+)=('|")([^"'>]*)('|"))*>/i
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kG5vF1/1)

I know that some suggest to use DOM parser instead of regular expression. But I think regular expression is enough for my case as I want to match `<html>` tag only.

Comment: is `<html` always appears at the first?

Comment: @AvinashRaj No problem of it. We can add `^` at the start of the pattern.

Comment: i mean is there an spaces exists before `<html` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the below regex and then get the attribute value pair from group index 1 and 3.

```
(?:<html|(?<!^)\G)\h*(?:([^=\n\h]+)=(['"])((?:\\\2|(?!\2).)*)\2)?
```

[`\G` reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897949/what-is-the-use-of-g-anchor-in-regex)

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kG5vF1/4)

Comment: Thanks. But I want to match `<html>` without attributes (the first case) too. I want to manipulate especially the values of the attributes `class` and `lang` and leave the other attributes as they are. If there is `class`, I want to append its value and if there is no `class`, I want to add `class`.

Comment: Sir, how to be a regex master like you, please give some advise. @AvinashRaj

Comment: @AvinashRaj Awesome! Upvoted. It is better to extract the attribute name and value separately so that the further process on the result could be easy without using string manipulation.

Comment: @BeingHuman  it's so simple. I started to learn regex (80%) a few months before (approx  10 months). This site teaches me about regex. People here a really awesome. I learned few things from the regex gurus (from SO). Some people  clears my doubts. I want to be a person from that some people. Yep, you could ask me any doubts in regex by commenting below my posts.

Comment: @Sithu get the attribute from index 1 and value from 3 https://regex101.com/r/kG5vF1/4

Comment: @AvinashRaj Can you please edit your answer with latest update? I will accept. BTW, what is the usage of `~` instead of `/`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks For reply, i'll comment your next regex posts to clear my doubts.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Although it seems working at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kG5vF1/4), unfortunately it is not working in real life. It's matching the attributes which are not related to `<html>`. [Please check my PhpFiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2dc507f309222bf89fb3)

Comment: @Sithu your input text on this question and input on phpfiddle are different . Please ask this as a new question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry for confusing about my question. My input in the question means to match one of the variations of `<html>`. One of them would be the start content of a HTML document. I would not state all of the HTML contents here. You might misunderstand it. My purpose is to do like in [PhpFiddle.com](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2dc507f309222bf89fb3). When I accepted your answer, it was working in regex101.com, but it is slightly different when I used your pattern with `preg_match_all`. I would not ask another duplicate question, but I will improve my question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @AvinashRaj And a lot of white-spaces are being matched and resulted in `$matches`.