# colorize string using grep -P

Tags: regex, colors, grep

I am using `grep` with `-P` (Perl regular expression) to colorize strings:

```
echo aaa bbb ccc ddd eee | grep --color=always -P "^[^#]*\K(bbb|ccc)|^"
```

in the above example, I want to colorize the string `bbb` and `ccc`. However, grep only colorizes the last one (`ccc`).

how can I modify my regular expression, so that both strings match and are colorized ?

Comment: Try `bbb|ccc`. What does `#` and BOS anchor `^` have to do with it ?

Comment: @sln - I don't want to colorize comments, thus the `#`. What do you mean "try bbb|ccc" ?

Comment: I'd imagine that `grep` colorizes only what it actually matches, not your regex used to match. (It is `ccc` here because `*` is greedy.)

Comment: Unless grep is not a line parser, it won't give you another match where the last one left off right ?

Comment: @sin Interestingly, adding `g` at the end makes it color `bbb`.  I'd say it's because if _first_ matches `ccc` (`*` being greedy) and then it goes on to match `bbb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your regex matches only one alternative: [From `^` start until `ccc`](https://regex101.com/r/T4SZot/2). But you want multiple matches. This could be achieved by chaining matches to start with use of [`\G` anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897949/what-is-the-use-of-g-anchor-in-regex).

Further it's needed to make the `[^#]*` [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) by attaching `?` for not skipping over a match.

```
echo aaa bbb ccc ddd eee | grep --color=always -P "\G[^#]*?\K(?:bbb|ccc)"
```

[image]

And the regex variant for multiline string.

```
(?:\G|\n)[^#]*?\K(?:bbb|ccc)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TjttL9/2)

---

A different approach can be the use of [pcre verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) for skipping anything until eol from `#`

```
#.*(*SKIP)(*F)|bbb|ccc
```

[See another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yeJiIs/1)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is using a perl command to do the match for you.

```
echo "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff" | perl -ne'print if s/(bbb|eee)/\e[1;35m$1\e[0m/g'
```