# Getting number of repetitions in regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Say I have a regex of `/\n(\d)+/`.

Let's say I test it against some random text:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
5aaaaaaaaa
4707aaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
923aaaaaaa
```

Is there a way I can get the number of times `\d` was repeated for each match?

I ask this because I'm using regex to do a find and replace on Notepad++ and was hoping I could achieve this end-result:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
Xaaaaaaaaa
XXXXaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
XXXaaaaaaa
```

Comment: So only replace the digits after newline and each? How about [`(?:\G|^)\d` with `X`](https://regex101.com/r/MfLzGW/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble Thank you that works! If you don't mind, could you explain how your regex works?

Comment: @mozicid `^` means "start of line", and `\G` means "end of last match" 'they're both *anchors*), so `(?:\G|^)` means "end of last match or start of a line"

Comment: you're welcome @mozicid! also lucas explained. glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match each digit at `^` start of line, the [`\G` anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897949/what-is-the-use-of-g-anchor-in-regex) can be used to chain matches. It matches at start of the string or where the previous match ended.

```
(?:\G|^)\d
```

Replace with

```
X
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MfLzGW/1)