# Getting number of repetitions in regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is kinda a follow-up question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45533438/), in which a solution was provided for Notepad++ but unsuitable for JavaScript.

Let's say I have some random text:

```
let text = `aaaaaaaaaa
            5aaaa8aaaa
            4707aaaaaa
            a1aaaaaaaa
            923aaaaaaa`;
```

Now I want to replace each digit that appear after a newline with `X`, to achieve this end-result:

```
`aaaaaaaaaa
 Xaaaa8aaaa
 XXXXaaaaaa
 a1aaaaaaaa
 XXXaaaaaaa`
```

The [solution provided for Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45533789/8424915) cannot be used here because the `\G` anchor is not available in JavaScript so `text.replace(/(?:\G|^)\d/gm, 'X')` does not work.

Are there any alternatives to using `\G` here, or any other ways to do this replacement in JavaScript?

Comment: try using `\b\d+`

Comment: @baao that only changes the first number on each line, i.e. it changes the 3rd line from `4707aaaaaa` to `X707aaaaaa` instead of `XXXXaaaaaa` as intended

Comment: Ah sorry - I've read it wrong then. @mozicid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```
text.replace(/\b(\d+)/g, m => 'X'.repeat(m.length))
```