# Regex: How to remove underscore from words beginning with

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need help with Regex to find all words beginning with `Denti` and remove underscores.

Example:

> Denti_Cal_Project_Status

Required Output:

> DentiCalProjectStatus

I could use Notepad++.

Comment: A nice task.  Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor the matches to `Denti` by use of the [`\G anchor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14898399/5527985).

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\bDenti)[^\W_]*\K_
```

See demo and explanation at regex101

- `\G(?!^)` chains matches to a previous match
- [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match
- `[^\W_]` is a [short](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#obnoxious) for `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Replace with empty string.