# PHP Replace Leading Zeros with Same Number of Spaces

Tags: php, preg-replace, trim

I'd like to replace a string like 0001 with "   1" with 3 spaces.

I've tried str_replace but that doesn't work on 0010.
I've tried some preg_replace but can't get the replacement right to replace the same number

I've written this basic thing and it works, but am looking for something more efficient if possible.

```
$pin = '0010';
$temp = ltrim($pin, '0');
$spaces = strlen($pin) - strlen($temp);
for ($x=1;$x<=$spaces;$x++) $temp = ' '.$temp;
echo $temp;
```

Closest I got with preg_replace was this but I'm not sure what to do with replacement:

```
preg_replace('/0+/', ' ', $pin)
```

Comment: Is efficiency of huge importance because you are performing this zero replacement on hundreds of thousands of strings in a single execution?

Answer (score 2):

`\G` for the win!

https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html

`\G` will match the start of the string and continue to match until it can't.

[What is the use of '\G' anchor in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14897949/2943403)

Match a zero from the start of the string, then match every following zero one-at-a-time.  Replace every matched zero with a space.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AcqK6))

```
$pin = '0010';
var_export(preg_replace('~\G0~', ' ', $pin));
```

Output:

```
'  10'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how to do this any easier with a regular expression, but you could make your other code more concise by using `str_repeat`:

```php
$pin = '0010';
$temp = ltrim($pin, '0');
$spaces = strlen($pin) - strlen($temp);
$new_pin = str_repeat(' ', $spaces) . $temp;
echo $new_pin;
```

Comment: You could combine some of these statements to make fewer lines of code, but I believe this will be more readable. I always prefer readable code to clever code.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> but am looking for something more efficient if possible

- First, note that a one-liner isn't necessarily efficient(as you tried for preg_replace() and regex is actually a bit slower since it gets compiled first).
- Second, you can better adopt for *just* a 2 pass approach over the string. This also edits the string in-place without extra string variables which is desirable in your case.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = '000010';
$len = strlen($str);

for($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i){
    if($str[$i] == '0'){
        $str[$i] = ' ';
    }else{
        break;
    }
}

echo $str;
```