# Regex to remove unnecessary period in Chinese translation

Tags: regex

I use a translator tool to translate English into Simplified Chinese.

Now there is an issue with the period.

In English at the finish point of a sentence, we use full stop "."
In Simplified Chinese, it is "。"which looks like a small circle.

The translation tool mistakenly add this "small circle" / full stop to every major subtitles.

Is there a way to use Regex or other methods to scan the translated content, and replace any "small circle" / Chinese full stop symbol when the line has only 20 characters or less?

Some test data like below

```
<h1>这是一个测试。<h1>
这是一个测试，这是一个测试而已，希望去掉不需要的。

测试。
这是一个测试，这是一个测试而已，希望去掉不需要的第二行。
```

It shall turn into:

```
<h1>这是一个测试<h1>
这是一个测试，这是一个测试而已，希望去掉不需要的。

测试
这是一个测试，这是一个测试而已，希望去掉不需要的第二行。
```

Difference:
Line 1  it only has 10 characters, and shall have Chinese full stop removed.
Line 4 is a sub heading, it only has 4 characters, and shall have full stop removed too.

By the way, I was told 1 Chinese word is two English characters.

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems like you are deciding whether to remove a fullstop based on whether that line is a "heading". How do you tell whether a line is a "heading"?

Comment: There are two ways.  First:  if a line has less than 20 characters, then it should not have a small full stop.  This will catch most of these errors.  Second: maybe this one is more accurate: if there is no comma in this line, it should not have a full stop.

Comment: Which programming language/regex engine are you using?

Comment: I am using an automation tool.
It can run c# or javascript, and regex.
I am not sure what engine version it is.

Comment: If I use the Chinese full stop symbol in the built in tester, it would remove all full stop.  I wish to have a condition. In this image below, remove the blue arrow highlighted ones.  When the line has a comma, the full stop is ok. https://i.imgur.com/iX0KSlN.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the approach 2

> Second: maybe this one is more accurate: if there is no comma in this line, it should not have a full stop.

to determine whether a full stop `。` should be removed.

#### Regex

```
/^(?=.*。)(?!.*，)([^。]*)。/mg
```

- `^` start of a line
- `(?=.*。)` match a line that contains `。`
- `(?!.*，)` match a line that doesn't contain `，`
- `([^。]*)。` anything that not a full stop before a full stop, put it in group 1

#### Substitution

```
$1
```

Check the test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/NcQOe9/1/)

But do mind this only removes the first full stop.

If you want to remove all the full stops, you can try [`(?:\G|^)(?=.*。)(?!.*，)(.*?)。`](https://regex101.com/r/yWQ8aZ/1/) but this only works for regex engines supports [`\G`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897949/what-is-the-use-of-g-anchor-in-regex) such as pcre.

Also, if you want to combine the two approaches(a line has no period `，` and the length is less than 20 characters), you can try [`^(?=.{1,20}$)(?=.*。)(?!.*，)([^。]*)。`](https://regex101.com/r/dKTflB/1/)